# How restore with StoreKit 2?

Tags: ios, storekit

iOS 15 introduces StoreKit 2. I'm looking at it to see whether I can adopt it in my existing apps, and I don't see how to do it. In particular, I don't see how to implement the required Restore functionality (in case the user has deleted my app, for instance).

I presume we are supposed to use `Transaction.latest(for:)`? Is that right?

But in my testing, it appears that if a user has done the purchase with StoreKit 1, that call returns `nil`. Is this true? Or if I'm doing it wrong, what's the correct way to migrate from StoreKit 1 to StoreKit 2, and how do we handle Restore?

Comment: According to [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/choosing_a_storekit_api_for_in-app_purchase) "In-app purchases that users make using either API are fully available to both APIs.".  Accessing [currentEntitlements](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/transaction/3851204-currententitlements) should be the equivalent of invoking restore purchases, but I don't have a suitable project to test this with.

Comment: Yeah, I really need someone to have gone down this road for me. :) I did see `currentEntitlements` and I tried that too, but it comes back `nil` if the purchase was made with the old API. OTOH I'm testing on the simulator with a store kit configuration; maybe things would be different if I tried actually talking to the online store... I'll keep banging away; it would be great to adopt the new API, it's so darned _simple._

Comment: Agree.  Unfortunately unless you are targeting IOS15 in a new app you have to support the original StoreKit as well

Comment: Not if I change the deployment target to iOS 15, though, right? — Hey, I think I just got it working with `currentEntitlements`. I'll let you know; if it works out, you should give it as an answer.

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes, `currentEntitlements` is the way, and I wouldn't have gotten there without your hint, so please go ahead and give it as an answer (with any elaboration you like). Thanks!

Comment: @matt Hi matt, does it mean, StoreKit2 will restore user's previous purchase, quietly without having user to tap on restore button explicitly? If that is the case, is it still mandatory to provide a restore button for StoreKit2, to comply with App Store publishing policy? Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can iterate over [`Transaction.currentEntitlements`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/transaction/3851204-currententitlements) in order to obtain all active subscription and previously purchased non-consumable products.

If you check this collection at launch you can silently restore any previous purchases without user interaction.

Comment: Does iterating over Transaction.currentEntitlements automatically restore Apple-hosted content downloads for non-consumable products, or just the meta data? How can one check to see that the download of an Apple-hosted product has completed (suppose it were large or the user's network were slow)?

Comment: Yeah, but when to do this? When app starts, etc. ? Has anyone tried Mercato StoreKit 2 wrapper on Git?

Comment: This is not recommended by Apple as best practice

Answer (score 16):

In Apple's SKDemo, they do [this](https://github.com/cntrump/SKDemo/blob/8a25badbf49683032384f61c69693db4412d4780/SKDemo/Views/MyCarsView.swift#L52)

```
Button("Restore Purchases", action: {
            async {
                //This call displays a system prompt that asks users to authenticate with their App Store credentials.
                //Call this function only in response to an explicit user action, such as tapping a button.
                try? await AppStore.sync()
            }
        })
```

I personally wanted to know if it was successful or not, so I wrapped it in a method

```
func restore() async -> Bool {
    return ((try? await AppStore.sync()) != nil)
}
```

And popped an alert accordingly

Comment: Cool but irrelevant to the actual question.

Comment: @matt To be fair, this is a quite good answer to your question "How restore with StoreKit 2". While the accepted answer seems to provide a solution for your use case, Apple offers an explicit API to "Restore with StoreKit 2". The docs for `AppStore.sync()` say: "Include some mechanism in your app, such as a Restore Purchases button, to let users restore their in-app purchases.". This is also discussed in the WWDC 2021 video "Meet StoreKit 2". I would expect to find exactly that API when reading your question.

Comment: I happen to be looking at StoreKit 2 demo app's code today too and stumble on this page. I think @Theo probably misunderstood it. The is from `AppStore.sync()` doc: "StoreKit automatically keeps signed transaction and renewal info up to date, so this should only be used if the user indicates they are missing access to a product they have already purchased." So it's optional and that's why the above answers didn't call the API.

Comment: @rayx No, I fully understand it :-) There are two different use cases and two different APIs. But matt's question "How restore with StoreKit 2" itself is ambiguous and can refer to both. matt was looking for one use case, and I was actually looking for the other use case when I stumbled on this question. Manas' answer was - for me - exactly the API I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Just to expand on Paulw11's correct answer, I'll just demonstrate the actual code I ended up with.

StoreKit 2 is really simple. Interacting with the store or with store information is primarily just a matter of opening successive envelopes. I've only got one in-app purchase, and it's non-consumable, so when the user asks to purchase it, this is what I do:

```
if let purchase = try? await product.purchase() {
    if case let .success(result) = purchase {
        if case let .verified(trans) = result {
            if trans.productID == IAPUtilities.productid {
                IAPUtilities.signalPurchaseSuccess()
                await trans.finish()
                return
            }
        }
    }
}
// but if we get here, we must have failed
IAPUtilities.signalPurchaseFailure()
```

Similarly, when the user asks to restore the purchase, this is what I do:

```
for await result in Transaction.currentEntitlements {
    if case let .verified(trans) = result {
        if trans.productID == IAPUtilities.productid {
            IAPUtilities.signalPurchaseSuccess()
            withUnsafeCurrentTask { task in
                task?.cancel()
            }
            await trans.finish()
            return
        }
    }
}
// but if we get here, we must have failed
IAPUtilities.signalRestorationFailure()
```

It appears, from my testing, as if the entitlement information is stored on disk somehow. Thus, if this is not a new installation of the app, the restoration is able to confirm the purchase without doing any networking. But if it *is* a new installation of the app, the entitlement information is obtained by talking over the network to the store. It does not appear that you need to call `finish` on this kind of transaction, but I'm doing it anyway, as it seems to do no harm.

Comment: Just in case it helps, Apple's StoreKit 2 demo app doesn't call `finished()` when iterating `Transaction.currentEntitlements` async sequence.

Comment: What is `withUnsafeCurrentTask` there for?

Comment: @sabiland do you have a different suggestion?

Comment: Sorry, I meant what is the purpose of it?

Comment: @sabiland And I'm asking, what's your alternative. I need to cancel the current task; how else do _you_ propose to do it?

Comment: Yes thank you. I didn't understand the code - that's why I asked you. Exactly today I started with async/await in Swift. Was only doing async/await in c# before.

Answer (score 0):

First I check if the user has transactions to restore

```
func canRestoreSubscription() async -> Bool  {
    let transactions = await fetchLatestTransactions()
    
    if transactions?.monthly == nil && transactions?.yearly == nil {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}

for await result in Transaction.currentEntitlements {

   if case let .verified(transaction) = result {
    // ...
   }
}
```

This only works on release mode and doesn't work on `debug mode` without `StoreKit Testing`, that is without a `Configuration.storekit`.